# Online streaming service with MEAN Stack. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, mean-stack

I'am currently researching the MEAN stack and as part of the investigation, am looking to build a music streaming service using the MEAN stack.

Is this possible with the MEAN stack? I would obviously need to store and, retrieve and load the MP3 files into an HTML 5 player. Also, all the data about the artists etc.

I have a round 5 month to do this.

Thanks for any advice/input.

Comment: `Is this possible with the MEAN stack?` isn't determining that _your job_? It seems like you are trying to outsource it. Moreover, it's an offtopic question for StackOverflow - come back if you've tried implementing it and hit a problem.

Comment: I'am certainly not trying to out source, simply looking for some advice from more experienced people in this field. Thank you for your comments.